# How to retrieve all data from firebase realtime database in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm trying to retrieve all data from realtime database with multiple children in flutter

[image: This is how my database looks like]

[image: This is how my database looks like. Expanded]

How do I retrieve all data. That is both accommodation and products?

This is how I fetch for them individually:

```
http.get(
        'https://flutter-buy.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}')
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
http.get(
        'https://flutter-buy.firebaseio.com.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried without specifying products or accommodation nodes in the request, like below (notice the `.json`):

```
http.get( 'https://flutter-buy.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=${_authenticatedUser.token}')
```

It seems like it is possible looking at their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/?r#section-param-shallow).

Comment: That is indeed the trick: you need a `/` before the `.json`, since otherwise that becomes part of the domain name.